# Compare first word of each line and replace if statement is true (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a script which reads only the first word of each line and store them. Once the first word is a `**`, it gets replaced by the last sensible stored word. Doesn't matter if it's from the previous line or 10 lines before. So far, I managed to get the first words, but got stucked:

```
words = []
with open('sample.txt','rw') as f:
    for line in f:
        words.append(line.split(None, 1)[0])
    print(words)
```

In example, I have a text file, which looks similar to this:

```
Lorem ipsum
** sit
amet consectetur
** adipiscing
** elit
** sed do
```

I want to convert it to look like this:

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem sit
amet consectetur
amet adipiscing
amet elit
amet sed do
```

Comment: Do you even tend to use object-oriented programming? Or you want it to run only on functions?

Comment: Just a note that your split method is wrong:  split(...)
    S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
    
    Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
    delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
    splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
    whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
    from the result.

Comment: I hope a moderator looks at this post. the poor guy is getting voted down for not being familiar enough with python, even though it is a basic question. this community is getting toxic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
word=""
other_file = open("other_file","w")
with open(some_file) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data = line.split()
        if data[0] == "**":
            data[0] = word
        else:
            word = data[0]
        other_file.write(' '.join(data))
other_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for this!
However, it stops working after the first line.

Comment: @Klajbar, oops, I forgot to add the loop. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably read the first Bytes till a space into String and compare it with  .startswith("**", 2). If true replace with current word( stored in a Variable) otherwise set currentWord-Variable to the read word.